# I am getting an error "Error: User validation failed" in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am getting an error after trying to use the `POST` method through `postman` to register a user. I have created a simple `Schema` for the `register` route.

Error:

```
Error in register: Error: User validation failed: password: Cast to string failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" (type Promise) at path "password"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:782:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:347:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2167:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2029:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:324:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:360:61)
    at /Users/harshmishra/Desktop/BackendApp/authSystem/app.js:46:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {

  errors: {
    password: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" (type Promise) at path "password"
        at SchemaString.cast (/Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/string.js:600:11)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1189:12)
        at model.$set (/Users/***/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1409:20)
        at model.$set (/Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1137:16)
        at model.Document (/Users/****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:162:12)
        at model.Model (/Users/****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:115:12)
        at new model (/Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4825:15)
        at /Users*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3132:22
        at /Users/*****/authSystem/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3168:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) {
      stringValue: '"Promise { <pending> }"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'string',
      value: [Promise],
      path: 'password',
      reason: null,
      valueType: 'Promise'
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed'
}
```

Schema:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

/register:

```
app.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;
        if (!(firstName && lastName && email && password)) {
         return res.status(400).send("All fields are required");
        }
        const existingUser =User.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser) {
          return res.status(401).send("User already exist");
        }
        const myEncrpytedPass = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 10);
        const user = await User.create({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email: email.toLowerCase(),
          password: myEncrpytedPass,
        });
        const token = await jwt.sign(
          {
            user_id: user._id,
            email,
          },
          process.env.SECRET_KEY,
          {
            expiresIn: "4h",
          }
        );
        user.token = token;
      return res.status(201).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in register:",error)
   }
})
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here? As I have followed the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings) of a mongoose but still I am getting the error.

What changes should I make here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that you need to change:

#### First

Try adding `await` before the `bcryptjs.hash()`. Looks like that function returns a Promise.

```js
const myEncrpytedPass = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 10);
```

---

#### Second

Add `return` before each `res.send`.

For example, if user exists, you will send this `res.send(401).send("User already exist")`, but because you didn't add `return`, function will continue, and will reach to the next `res.status(201).json(user)` response. This will throw an error like `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` because you have already sent the response to the user.

Comment: After adding `await` before `bcryptjs.hash()` I am getting an error ```Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client```.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: After adding `return` before every `res.send()` I am not getting `user` from `User.create()` as I have also checked in`console.log()`.

Comment: Do you have any errors now? What is the response from you server? Maybe the user already exists so the sever returns 401, and `User.create()` part will not be executed.

Comment: No, Now there are no errors but I have sent` new user details` but still getting `All fields are required`.

Comment: Maybe you are not sending it correctly. Try to `console.log(req.body)` and see what your server is getting.

Comment: Already done that. console.log: ```req.body: {
  fistName: 'First',
  lastName: 'Last',
  email: 'test.hee@gtes.com',
  password: '1233445'
} ```

Comment: Well, you have a typo. You are sending `fistName` instead of `firstName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;
        if (!(firstName && lastName && email && password)) {
          res.status(400).send("All fields are required");
        }
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser) {
          res.send(401).send("User already exist");
        }
        const myEncrpytedPass = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 10);
        const user = await User.create({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email: email.toLowerCase(),
          password: myEncrpytedPass,
        });
        const token = await jwt.sign(
          {
            user_id: user._id,
            email,
          },
          process.env.SECRET_KEY,
          {
            expiresIn: "4h",
          }
        );
        user.token = token;
        res.status(201).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in register:",error)
   }
})
```

You need to await jwt sign and bcrypt